# Передать HTML файл контроллеру в ASP.NET CORE

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor

Как вернуть контроллеру не файл Razor в вьюхе а передать html файл из папки wwwroot например?

```
[Route("[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("Index/{id}")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return /*файл html из папки wwwroot*/
        }
    }
```

Comment: А чем вам Razor не нравится? Статический Html это тот же Razor только без Razor синтаксиса и инструкций.

Comment: Просто при работе с  Razor из за невнимательности бывает тупяк на  целый день, решил для интереса с html попробовать проект сделать. Плюс к тому устал ждать запуск студии после исправлений.

Comment: файлы из папки wwwroot и так доступны по пути - в этом случае контроллер не нужен

Comment: @Grundy просто хотел абстрактно установить маршрутизацию атрибутами, из-за этого интересуюсь реально ли такое.

Comment: Никто не мешает читать файл и отдавать строку, читать можно любой файл в системе. Поэтому - конечно возможно, но зачем, когда есть специальные инструменты?

Comment: Я например настроил API который передает из бд инфу, но какою именно зависит от числа которое я установил в атрибуте [Id] и далее JS скрипт с этим значение работает. Если все размещения статичных файлов через папки то как тогда в http установить Id. Извиняюсь, как смог объяснил (ужасно).

Comment: Не понял вопрос.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110570/discussion-between-grundy-and-al-tamir).